# Enum showing numeric value instead of text value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, enums

Below is my Enum. When I access my Enum, it is showing 0 for N and 1 for IC.

I want to get N and IC

```
 Public Enum StatusCode
    <Description("New")> _
    N

    <Description("Incomplete")> _
    IC
 End Enum
```

This is my vb code

```
oBLL.StatusCode = StatusCode.N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not showing the wrong value at all, it's showing the correct value (`N = 0`). However, it would appear that what you are really after is the *name* of the `enum` and not the *value*. To get the name you can simply call `ToString`

```
oBLL.StatusCode = StatusCode.N.ToString()
```

This will internally call [Enum.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx) does. It acts as a front for `int` type (or other numeric type when specified). Since `N` is first and `IC` is second, they respectively are assigned `int` values 0 and 1.

**My advice:** [constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyxe49xw.aspx) will be best suited for what you're trying to achieve.

```
Public Shared Class StatusCode
    Public Const N As String = "N"
    Public Const IC As String = "IC"
End Class

' ...

oBLL.StatusCode = StatusCode.N
```

If however you insist on using enum, you can get the string representation this way:

```
oBLL.StatusCode = Enum.GetName(StatusCode.GetType(), StatusCode.N)
```

Note however that obtaining this value at runtime implies [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which should be avoided.

Comment: what is the solution to my issue ? Is it better to declare constants ?

Comment: I am interested to know how constants would be better suited? An `enum` effectively *is* a constant.

Comment: @James it comes down to using the right type for the right job. Of course you can convert an enum to its string representation but if you're not even using the enum as is (as the post suggests) then what's the point declaring this enum at all? Just use plain string constants instead.

Comment: @James plus, obtaining the string representation of an enum implies reflection.

Comment: @Crono I am not saying that if the OP purely needs strings that `const` isn't a better (and in fact more efficient) way to go. However, I'd argue that your answer is *very* subjective. The OP has attributes associated with their `enum` therefore that implies *context* - what context can you give to a `const`? Another argument would be that it's more efficient/reliable to test `int` for equality than it is `string` so, actually, using an enum *would* be the right tool for the job. "*...runtime implies reflection, which should be avoided*" - again completely subjective.

Comment: @James given that the OP obviously never expected the enums values to be numeric I feel quite comfortable assuming he never meant to test numeric equality for status codes to begin with. As for context, this is subjective in itself. What is a context? Is is a class scope? Attributes? What would make it impossible to work with constants in respect of the desired context?

Comment: @James oh and reflection *should* be avoided. This is hardly subjective as there's a cost associated with it. Granted in some scenarios it's nearly unavoidable but here I feel safe believing that's not the case, based on the OP comments.

Comment: @Crono I never said it would be *impossible* to have context around `const` I was simply pointing out that it would lead to further work so your suggestion that "*const are better suited*" is subjective (IMO). On the reflection stuff, yeah there is a cost and if there is a non-reflection solution to your problem then 9x out of 10 it's better to use that. However, your answer was suggesting that it should be avoided completely (i.e. in all scenarios) which is why I said it was a subjective comment.

Comment: @James I think I see your point but nonetheless I believe it's a workaround worth proposing. Since obviously the enum type isn't used anywhere yet (otherwise there is NO WAY the OP wouldn't know about enum mechanics), the effort should be minimal. As for what I seem to be suggesting about reflection... well my english is far from perfect (probably obvious at this point :) ), but still, I'd think the conditional form in "**should** be avoided" would prevent the reader to think that it **must** be avoided in all scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Did not test in VB
But in C# I do not get that behavior
The last two lines do not even pass the compiler (cannot implicitly convert)

```
public enum enumRole : byte { [Description("First Level Review")] fstLvlRev = 1, [Description("Second Level Review")] secLvlRev = 2 };  
public MainWindow() {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(enumRole.secLvlRev);
    enumRole ee = enumRole.secLvlRev;
    string es = enumRole.secLvlRev.ToString();
    byte eb = (byte)enumRole.secLvlRev;

    string ees = enumRole.secLvlRev;
    byte eeb = enumRole.secLvlRev;
```